# how to convert an image which is given as matrix representation to grayscale image?

Tags: image-processing, rgb, grayscale

consider the an image as  [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9] matrix. How we can convert given image to grayscale image. I know that we need to get r,g,b values of each pixel. And using 0.2*R+0.7*G+0.1*B formula we can get the grayscale values of each pixel.But how can I get the r,g,b values of each pixel.
Or is there a completely another method the convert given image to grayscale?

Comment: You should probably find out how many bits are allotted for each of R, G, B color, convert each number in the matrix to an RGB vector and apply the conversion formula on the vector.

Comment: It's an RGB image, total 24 bit for a pixel. So 8 bit for each channel. Can you tell me how can I convert each number in the matrix to RGB vector?

Comment: That greatly depends on what programming language you're going to use.

Answer (score 0):

So far, you need to split each 24 bit pixel value to R,G,B component. As an example in matlab:

```
% If x is a 24 bit string in base 2
r_binary = x(1:8);
g_binary = x(9:16);
b_binary = x(17:24);
r_value = base2dec(r_binary,2);
g_value = base2dec(g_binary,2);
b_value = base2dec(b_binary,2);

% If x is a decimal value
r_value = rem(x,2^8);
g_value = rem(bitshift(x,-8),2^8);
b_value = rem(bitshift(x,-16),2^8);
```